# Custom element in VictoryLine chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, charts, victory-charts

I am using [Victory-Native](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/victory-native) to display the chart in the app. In my chart I have 2 lines. One is an infinite horizontal line and the other with an arrow.

And to my question, is it possible to render a line with an arrow in VictoryLine component? Also, in addition, I would want to have a box(gray) below of the infinite line.

**The expected image is this one.**

[image]

**Actual/current result:**

[image]